# PHP Foreach Array building with nested array

Tags: php, foreach, multidimensional-array

This is in reference to a CRM I am building.

I am trying to get data from phone contacts in my database and then separate them by the hour of day then filter through the contacts by each hour and count them. This is all generated into an array which is then placed into a graph.

So the goal is to count the calls by hour per provider that the call came in on. I can do this just fine by the agent, but now I want it to generate by provider. Here is a screenshot for reference. The highlighted section is supposed to be separate lines but they are currently overlapping because the data is not correctly generated.

[Screenshot](http://simplyconnectedusa.com/crm_screenshot.jpg)

Here is the PHP:

```
$user_level = $_POST['user_level'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$date = date("m/d/Y");

$today_manager_plot = "SELECT * FROM contacts AS c INNER JOIN skills AS s ON s.skill_id=c.skill_id WHERE start_date='$date' AND s.type='0'";
$today_query_manager_plot = $db->query($today_manager_plot);
$rows = $today_query_manager_plot->num_rows;
$today_plot_array = array();
$plot_array = array();
$providers = array();

$t=0;
foreach($today_query_manager_plot as $p)    {
    $providers[$t]['skill_id'] = $p['skill_id'];
    $providers[$t]['skill_name'] = $p['skill_name'];
    $providers[$t]['vendor_color'] = $p['vendor_color'];
    $t++;
}
$provider_array = array_unique($providers, SORT_REGULAR);
$i=0;

foreach($today_query_manager_plot as $tq)   {
    if($tq['type'] == 0)    {
        $hour = date("H", strtotime($tq['start_time']));
        $today_plot_array[$i] = $hour;
        $i++;
    }
}

natsort($today_plot_array);
$hour_array = array_unique($today_plot_array, SORT_REGULAR);

function total_calls_by_provider($hour, $array, $skill_id)  {
    $i=0;
    foreach($array as $a)   {
        $high = strtotime($hour.":59:59");
        $low = strtotime($hour.":00:00");
        if(($low <= strtotime($a['start_time']) && $high >= strtotime($a['start_time'])) && $a['skill_id'] == $skill_id)    {
            $i++;
        }   
    }
    return $i;
}

foreach($provider_array as $pa) {
    foreach($hour_array as $h)  {
        $provider = total_calls_by_provider($h, $today_query_manager_plot, $pa['skill_id']);
        $total_calls_array[] = array(
            "x" => intval($h),
            "y" => intval($provider)
        );          
    }

    $plot_array[] = array(
        "color" => $pa['vendor_color'],
        "name" => $pa['skill_name'],
        "data" => $total_calls_array
    );      
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Provider info:array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "Pink"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "PinkADT"
    ["data"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["x"]=>
        int(9)
        ["y"]=>
        int(2)
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "Red"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "RedADT"
    ["data"]=>
     array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["x"]=>
        int(9)
        ["y"]=>
        int(2)
      }
      [1]=>
       array(2) {
        ["x"]=>
        int(9)
        ["y"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is if you look at the output the second array is generating PinkADT and RedADT data in the data nested array. Each should have just it's own data. So RedADT should look like this:

```
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "Red"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "RedADT"
    ["data"]=>
     array(1) {
      [0]=>
       array(2) {
        ["x"]=>
        int(9)
        ["y"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
  }
```

I have been playing with this for 2 days and I cannot figure out why it is including PinkADT data with the RedADT data in the data array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is in the inner foreach loop:

```
foreach($provider_array as $pa) {
    foreach($hour_array as $h)  {
        //this foreach should be related to the $pa provider only, 
        //it seems you are not filtering this array  
        $provider = total_calls_by_provider($h, $today_query_manager_plot, $pa['skill_id']);
        $total_calls_array[] = array(
            "x" => intval($h),
            "y" => intval($provider)
        );          
     } 

     $plot_array[] = array(
     "color" => $pa['vendor_color'],
     "name" => $pa['skill_name'],
     "data" => $total_calls_array
 );
```

}

i would implement a filter function that takes the `$hour_array` and gives back the desired information, like this

```
foreach($provider_array as $pa) {
    foreach(provider_filter($hour_array,$pa) as $h)  {
        $provider = total_calls_by_provider($h, $today_query_manager_plot, $pa['skill_id']);
        $total_calls_array[] = array(
            "x" => intval($h),
            "y" => intval($provider)
        );          
     } 

     $plot_array[] = array(
     "color" => $pa['vendor_color'],
     "name" => $pa['skill_name'],
     "data" => $total_calls_array
 );
```

}

EDIT: now I see the mistake, you should flush your array, because you are just adding to it in every iteration.

change

```
$total_calls_array[] = array(
```

to

```
$total_calls_array = array(
```

to make it look like this

```
foreach($provider_array as $pa) {
    $total_calls_array = array()
    foreach($hour_array as $h)  {
        $provider = total_calls_by_provider($h, $today_query_manager_plot, $pa['skill_id']);
        $total_calls_array[] = array(
            "x" => intval($h),
            "y" => intval($provider)
        );          
     } 

     $plot_array[] = array(
     "color" => $pa['vendor_color'],
     "name" => $pa['skill_name'],
     "data" => $total_calls_array
 );
```

}

Comment: The data is being filtered. The hour_array is already filtered and I already filtered my provider_array down to just what I need. Then the third filter is in the function. That filters it by the unique skill_id. I have used this method on several other function/array filtering and it always works. The function states if the skill_id is equal to the $pa['skill_id'] then it should add 1 and loop until done. That statement should be enough but it acts like it isn't using it.

Comment: yes... it's filtered but not by provider, it's just filtered for repetitions as far as I can tell by looking at your code.

Comment: If I use the same function and change it from making an array to just make a table it works just fine. So I know it is filtering just fine.

Comment: To be clear it is supposed to make a new array every time it runs through the loop. That is on purpose. The arrays generated in the loop are then called into another array called 'data'. Look at the original question and look at the current output then the desired output.

Comment: You are right, I edited it again, to empty the array in the outer `foreach` loop

Comment: HOLY HELL!! I can't believe I missed that!! I fixed this same issue like 3 times yesterday and I just didn't see it. THX!!! It's working great now.

Answer (score 0):

If I do this it works fine, but I need it in array format because I need to plot the locations on a graph:

```
foreach($provider_array as $pa) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>".$pa['skill_name']."</td></tr>";
    foreach($hour_array as $h)  {
        $provider = total_calls_by_provider($h, $today_query_manager_plot, $pa['skill_id']);
        $skill_id = $pa['skill_id'];
        $hour = date('g:i a',strtotime($h.':00'));
        echo "<tr><td>".$hour."</td><td>".$provider."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

But I need it in array format that I had set for the data to plot.

Comment: I edited my answer, you are right, it's filtered OK!

Comment: Using your correction it will only generate the first array, but not any after that. I needs the [] to make each loop into any array entry.  So that doesn't work. The needed array is a nested array in a multidimensional array.